# Encrypting the output using select statement on oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, encryption

**Updated question:**

I am working with scenario where the source oracle schema do not have a field say "Date of Birth" saved in encrypted format but when using select statement I want output to be in encrypted format. I do not know the version of the oracle to find the appropriate function in the documentations.

I have worked with MySQL and I am familiar with "password()" function.  I am looking for similar function for Oracle in SQL not PL/SQL as I cannot use that in the application I am using it should be one line query to fetch the results. I tried using DBMS_CRYPTO as per the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_crypto.htm#i1004271 but I am getting error fetching data on my application could be possible that DB version may not be supporting DBMS_CRYPTO.

Any other suggestion on which function can be used to display non-encrypted field in encrypted format when using select on Oracle(thin) query?

Comment: What exactly is your question? If you have a problem with a specific query, then **[edit]** your question add the query and the exact error message you get.  ([formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - [edit] your question do **not** post code in comments

Comment: You can find your Oracle version by querying `v$version` and checking the row containing `'Oracle Database'`; or else just start SQL\*Plus and check the *'Connected to'*  part of the banner. I'm not sure what you mean by *where the source oracle schema do not some important field saved in encrypted format*, though.

Comment: thanks I have update the question to be more specific

Comment: It would help if you could tell us what you have done and what error you're getting.